# Debug level Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

is there any way to prevent the Common Lisp console to print messages after I print out an error?

for example if i use this instruction

`(error "Invalid input")`

The console prints out

```
ERROR: Invalid Input"

  1 (abort) Return to debug level 3.
  2 Return to level 2.
  3 Return to debug level 2.
  4 Return to level 1.
  5 Return to debug level 1.
  6 Return to level 0.
  7 Return to top loop level 0.
```

Is there any way to not print anything after the error message?

Comment: `ERROR` does not print an error message; it signals an error condition. If you don't handle the condition the debugger is invoked, which will print the error and prompt for a restart to continue execution with.

Comment: What is this question actually about? Are you delivering a Lisp application as an executable, and would like to get rid of debugger interaction with error conditions?

Comment: No, i just want to print that message without the debugger that calls for debugging options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CL-USER 50 > (setf *debugger-hook*
                   (lambda (c v)
                     (format t "~a~%" c)
                     (abort c)))
#<anonymous interpreted function 4060001CBC>

CL-USER 51 > (error "Invalid input")
Invalid input
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't want to disable the debugger globally one way of doing this is to actually handle the error.  CL has an extremely comprehensive system for dealing with errors and from restarting from them, but it can be used in pretty simple ways:

```
(defmacro aborting-from-errors (&body forms)
  `(handler-case
       (progn
         ,@forms)
     (error (condition)
       (format *error-output* "~&error: ~A~%" condition)
       (abort condition))))
```

And now if I have a function like this:

```
(defun maybe-explode (&optional (raisep nil))
  (if raisep
      (error "exploded")
    t))
```

Then

```
> (aborting-from-errors
    (format t "~&result ~A~%" (maybe-explode))
    'result)
result t
result

> (aborting-from-errors
    (format t "~&result ~A~%" (maybe-explode t))
    'result)
error: exploded
```

What is happening here is that, if an `error` is raised (that is, a condition whose type is `error` or some subtype of it), then `aborting-from-errors` will handle that via the [`handler-case`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_hand_1.htm) it has wrapped around the code, printing it prettily to `*error-output*`, and calling [`abort`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_abortc.htm).  What `abort` does is look for a restart named [`abort`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/r_abort.htm) and which is either associated with the particular condition raised or not associated with any condition, and invoke it.  And the final bit of the puzzle is that the system arranges for there to be a restart named `abort` available at the top level.

There are a lot of things you can do with the CL condition system, and in particular restarts are very powerful tools.